# How can I use jquery trigger from custom js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, markdown

I want to use [markdownx](https://github.com/adi-/django-markdownx) plugin for Django. Documentation says about [js event handlers](https://github.com/adi-/django-markdownx#js-event-handlers), but I can't run this simple example:

```
$('.markdownx').on('markdownx.update', function(e, response) {
    console.log("UPDATE" + response);
});
```

I copy & paste this string into Chrome JavaScript Console, but nothing happened on updating markdown field (no `UPDATE` in console). How can I use this trigger?

Sorry, I'm very newbie in js and jquery.

Comment: Do you have any element with class `markdownx`?

Comment: Yes, of course, I have [this element](https://github.com/adi-/django-markdownx#widgets-template).